# Find the function called when user interacts with an exe

Tags: exe, reverse-engineering, radare2

I have an exe which I am trying to understand how it works. Whe I click on one of the UI elements of the exe , I think it is making a network request and receiving data . How would I trace what is being done by the exe ? Is there a way to use dynamic analysis to tell me what is executing when I click on a user element ?

Comment: If it does indeed send data through the network, you could capture that data with tools like Wireshark.

Comment: I can capture the data but I think the data is a binary string. The application has encoded the string to decrypt inside th exe

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, you can try a Reverse Engineer approach. Some time ago I used [JustDecompile](https://blog.anirudhmergu.com/code/reverse-engineer-a-windows-exe-application-to-get-its-source-code-and-vs-project/?utm_source=quora&utm_medium=textlink&utm_campaign=quora_referral) and it worked.